# TypeError: WebElementCondition did not resolve to a WebElement: [object Object]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

**Issue:** In a particular webpage i want to wait for a particular element and then perform operation on that element.

**Code Used:**

```
    //Official webapp URL
    browser.driver.get('http://ubet-feature-qa.opal.dnb.com');

    // variable to get the particular element
    var userNameDisplayedOnHomePageField = element(by.css('[ng-if="authSrv.getUserName()"]'));

    //function to wait for the element and return the element availability
    this.isLoggedIn = function(){ 
    browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(userNameDisplayedOnHomePageField));
    return userNameDisplayedOnHomePageField.isDisplayed();
        };
```

**Expected Result:**
It should return the element availability either **true** or **false**

**Actual Result:**
Getting below error message, not sure why is this..

> TypeError: WebElementCondition did not resolve to a WebElement:
>   [object Object]

Screenshot[image]

Answer (score 5):

A Selenium condition cannot resolve a Protractor `ElementFinder`.

You could use a `protractor.ExpectedConditions` instead of a `protractor.until` condition:

```js
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var button = element(by.css("..."));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(button), 1000);
button.click();
```

You could also use a Selenium element with a Selenium condition:

```js
var until = protractor.until;
var button = browser.findElement(by.css("..."));

browser.wait(until.elementIsVisible(button), 1000).then(function(button){
   button.click();
});
```

And a another way would be to get the `WebElement` from the `ElementFinder`:

```js
var until = protractor.until;
var button = element(by.css("..."));

browser.wait(until.elementIsVisible(button.getWebElement()), 1000).then(function(button){
   button.click();
});
```

Comment: But when i use your another way (like below) i am getting the same error.
var until = protractor.until;
browser.wait(until.elementIsVisible(by.css("...")), 1000).then(function(button){
   button.click();
});

Comment: My bad, the `until.elementIsVisible` works only with a web element and not a locator. I've fixed the code example.